# Cron task not running

Tags: node.js, shell, cron, vps

i've configure a cron task for running a NodeJS script everyday.

`crontab -l`

[image: crontab]

But my script is never executed (the script write data on a file, and the last modification time of this file is never updated.) When I run the script manually, it's working.

I've no idea why it's not working

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the full path of your node binary.
If you can't find it run the following:

```
whereis node
```

That should give you something like:

> /usr/bin/node

In this example, your crontab line would look like this:

> 55 23 * * * /usr/bin/node /getGames/

Also be wary that this will differ depending on how you installed node.

Comment: What's the output of your "whereis node" command? Did you put that on the crontab?

Comment: Output : `node: /usr/bin/node /usr/include/node /usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz`

And `crontab -l` -> `45 11 * * * /usr/bin/node /getGames/index.js`